# Отслеживание новых файлов в директории, дистрибутив Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, консоль

С помощью какой команды для bash скрипта я бы мог отследить появление нового файла в директории и вывести его имя на терминал?

Или похожие примеры.

Comment: Например, `ls > /tmp/1` в начале скрипта, а в цикле `ls >/tmp/2; if cmp /tmp/1 /tmp2; ...` Если именно добавление, то вместо `cmp` можно вызвать `diff` и проанализировать ее вывод

Comment: `man inotifywait`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, добавлю, что из пакета `inotify-tools` его обычно нет из коробки... 2 OP: а если ни какая эффективность не важна, то можно на коленке слепить скрипт с вечным циклом из `cmp` или `diff`'а, `ls`'а и пары переменных...

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, на всякий случай замечу, что inotify не работает через NFS и через samba по моему тоже не работает

Comment: @PavelGridin, устаревшая информация? https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_3.0_Features_added/changed

Comment: @0andriy, это хорошо, `QFileSystemWatcher` в Qt работает через inotify

Answer (score 2):

Через find, если устраивает проверка раз в минуту

```
find /path -mmin -1 -ls
```

Через цикл добавить чтобы команда запускалась раз в минуту
последние версии find даже поддерживают дробную часть -mmin т.е. можно указать 0.5 - что равно 30 секундам. соответственно запускать можно чаще. по дополнительным параметрам:

```
man find
```